# grep to sort filter file names

Tags: vim, grep

I have a file which has the following data.

```
>Cluster 1
0       1a, >bcd
>Cluster 2
0       1a, >cfg
>Cluster 3
0       5a, >jkl
1       8a, >lmk
2       3a, >qwe
3       9a, >oiu
```

I need a list of all clusters which have more than one '>' listed under them.

I used `grep '>' 'filename'|grep '>'|grep '>'` But this gave the same exact list again:

```
>Cluster 1
0       1a, >bcd
>Cluster 2
0       1a, >cfg
>Cluster 3
0       5a, >jkl
1       8a, >lmk
2       3a, >qwe
3       9a, >oiu
```

But the output should be only cluster 3:

```
>Cluster 3
0       5a, >jkl
1       8a, >lmk
2       3a, >qwe
3       9a, >oiu
```

How do I solve this using grep and or/other vim commands?

Comment: Why would you expect that command to give only cluster 3 as the output? You ask grep which lines have `>`, and it returns them. In this case, all lines have a `>`. Then you filter those lines by making sure they have a `>` in them... which is still every line.

Comment: I actually used 3 greps, sorry for the confusion. Edited the question now

Comment: I suspect your life will be easier if you just write a short Python script, rather than doing this with only shell tools.

Comment: Are all lines numbered like that? And contain the `>`? If so, the solution is not complicated.

Comment: yes, they are numbered the same way and have >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a regex with the following conditions to match the *unwanted* lines:

- Start on a line with `>` as the first character, and match the whole line
- Match a complete line that begins with 0
- Match, without counting it, a `>`.

This will match your unwanted groups, with the last item being key: it matches the start of the next group guaranteeing that the current group has only one sub-line.

You can then replace this match by nothing, effectively deleting groups < 2. In Vim:

```
:%s/^>.*\n0.*\n\ze>//
```

Comment: could you please explain how I would give it as a command to search the entire file?

Comment: That's already done by `%`, which is a range shortcut for "whole file". Just open your file in vim and type the command. Hit enter.